# SceneKit Swift3 compiler-error

Tags: animation, compiler-errors, 3d, swift3, scenekit

I'm trying to run animated "DAE" model in SceneKit:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "art.scnassets/Player(walking)", withExtension: "dae")
    let sceneSource = SCNSceneSource(url: url!, options: [SCNSceneSource.LoadingOption.animationImportPolicy: SCNSceneSource.AnimationImportPolicy.playRepeatedly] )
    let animationIds: NSArray = sceneSource?.identifiersOfEntries(withClass: CAAnimation)

    for eachId in animationIds {
        let animation: CAAnimation = (sceneSource?.entryWithIdentifier(eachId as! String, withClass: CAAnimation.self))!
        animations.add(animation)
    }
    character?._walkAnimations = animations
```

But compiler It throws on the line:

*let animationIds: NSArray = sceneSource?.identifiersOfEntries(withClass: CAAnimation)*

and writes an error:

**Cannot convert value of type '[String]?' to specified type 'NSArray'**

Please help me to fix that problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are converting `[String]?` to `NSArray` and then convert each element to `String` again, no need of it simply use Swift native `Array` and wrapped the optional value with `if let` or `guard let`.

```
guard let animationIds = sceneSource?.identifiersOfEntries(withClass: CAAnimation) else {
    return
}
for eachId in animationIds {
    if let animation = sceneSource?.entryWithIdentifier(eachId, withClass: CAAnimation.self) {
        animations.add(animation)
    }
}
character?._walkAnimations = animations
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.